# Phonotactic Parallels to Pyysalo's Laryngeal and Schwa

Tags: linguistic-typology, proto-indo-european, phonotactics

Jouna Pyysalo has a rather unique reconstruction of Proto-Indo-European, that he calls System PIE (documented [here](http://pielexicon.hum.helsinki.fi/), amongst other places) and describes as a new form of monolaryngealism.

This reconstruction has a single laryngeal *h which, like other consonants in his view regularly alternates with a voiced alternant *ɦ based on morphophonological conditions.

It also has a single schwa *ɑ, which is not merely an allophone of *e next to what would typically be called *h₂, but develops into that *a through coalescence with an *e as the language develops.

An especially curious aspect is that the laryngeal and the schwa must always appear next to each other. According to him there is never a laryngeal without either a preceding or following schwa, and there is never a schwa without a preceding or following laryngeal. I.e. *hɑ and *ɑh are both phonotactically valid, but *ehe or *tɑt are not (neglecting voicing for now).

This seems extremely unlikely to me.

Are there parallels to such an extreme phonotactic restriction in languages that have survived to be documented? I.e. is there are language with a pair of phonemes A & B (and it is clear from Pyysalo's description that we are dealing with phonemes here, not mere allophones) that satisfies both of the following:

- No A can occur without either a preceding B or a following B
- No B can occur without either a preceding A or a following A

Comment: Do you count automatic effects of consonants on vowels? For example, [e] and [o] in Greenlandic only appear adjacent to uvular phonemes /q r/, so you can have [qe eq qo oq ʁe eʁ ʁo oʁ], but you cannot have [#e# #o# te# #et to# #ot pe# #ep po# #op]. Would that count?

Comment: do the uvulars appear next to other vowels? If so that wouldn't be an example as it would satisfy only one of the two criteria

Comment: Not really, no. There are only three phonemic vowels, /a i u/, and they’re all affected by uvulars: /i u/ are lowered to [e o] (or [ε ɔ]), and /a/ is retracted to [ɑ]. So [e/ε o/ɔ ɑ] only appear next to uvulars (phonemic), nowhere else; and since Greenlandic doesn’t allow many clusters, uvulars only appear next to lowered/retracted vowels.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you actually discount allphones – I’d missed that at first read. Not an example, then!

Comment: yeah, with allophones it's not especially unusual, but I don't think there's any way to analyse Pyysalo's model so that ɑ (or h) is an allophone of anything else